# could not translate host name "database" to address: Try again

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

пытаюсь запустить миграции на джанго через docker-compose,получаю эту ошибку

```
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)                                                                                                                                                                      docker:default
[+] Creating 1/0
 ✔ Container log-serv-database-1  Created                                                                                                                                                              0.0s 
[+] Running 1/1
 ✔ Container log-serv-database-1  Started                                                                                                                                                              1.0s 
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)                                                                                                                                                                      docker:default
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "database" to address: Try again


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 75, in handle
    self.check(databases=[database])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 419, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 34, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1303, in check
    *cls._check_indexes(databases),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1695, in _check_indexes
    connection.features.supports_covering_indexes or
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/features.py", line 92, in is_postgresql_11
    return self.connection.pg_version >= 110000
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 329, in pg_version
    with self.temporary_connection():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 603, in temporary_connection
    with self.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 259, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 235, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "database" to address: Try again
```

мой docker-compose файл:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  web-app:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      context: . 
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
      - ./service:/service
    
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 "
    
    depends_on:
      - database


  database:
    image: postgres
```

мои django db настройки:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME':'postgres001',
        'USER':'postgres',
        'PASSWORD':'My password',
        'HOST':'database',
        'PORT':5432,
    }
}
```

как я могу пофиксить это?